# Only allowing secure SSL connections (Google App Engine flexible)

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform, custom-domain

I've got essentially a React app in GAE flexible and a separate API app (Node.JS), also in GAE flexible.

I went through the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl), and when I run `gcloud app domain-mappings list` I get:

[image]

When I check in SSL verification sites and type in the domain it checks out.

When I type in my custom domain in the address bar as (ex: `mydomain.ai`) it connects as "Not Secure". Sure, if I explicitly type in `https://` all is fine.

Any ideas on how to make it **always** secure, no matter if user types in `https` or not? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Ryan.

Of course you can allow http - but it's **security issue**.

I don't know if such an operation is possible from the level of the management module, but you can certainly solve it with the principle - **redirect**. at the proxy / load balancer level.

no matter what http you use (Apache, Nginx etc..)

You can redirect all http domain requests to https in **ngix.conf**:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

> For example, if the visitor opens http://example.com/page2 in the
>   browser, Nginx will redirect the request to https://example.com/page2.